# Python multiprocessing Pool hangs trying to dequeue tasks from an empty task queue

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, freeze

in my application most of the actual work is done in plugins. For ease of use I implemented two ways of invoking a plugin (let's call it `test`): Either invoke `tool test` or use `python path/to/test.py`.

In order to avoid having to add the if `__name__ == "__main__": ...` boilerplate to every plugin my tool instead utilizes the `__main__` package and only triggers plugin execution if the path in `argv[0]` (or `__main__.__file__`, given `__main__` has a `__file__` attribute) ends in `.py`. If that's the case I analyze the AST of the module to decide whether it is in fact a plugin for my tool and if it is, it gets loaded and executed.

Most of the work modules do is automatically parallelized. I noticed a hang whenever using the second way of invoking a module. It does however work fine if I do not use the mp pool. Here's a somewhat minimal example that produces the same effect:

`tool/__init__.py`

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pathlib import Path

def task(bar: int):
    return bar * 2

def do_work():
    foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    with Pool(1) as pool:
        foo = pool.map(task, foo)

    print(foo)

def main():
    """ entry point (set in setup.cfg) """
    do_work() # works fine

def check_direct():
    import __main__

    if not (importer := getattr(__main__, '__file__', None)):
        return

    importer = Path(importer)
    if importer.suffix == '.py':
        # no static analysis for brevity
        do_work() # hangs

check_direct()
```

`test.py`

```py
import tool
```

Running `tool` works fine, however running `python test.py` causes it to hang.

Any idea what's happening? With a debugger attached I see that it tries to dequeue a task from mp.Pool's `_taskqueue`, which seems to be empty for some reason - causing it to hang.

Using `multiprocess` instead yielded the same result, as did running `do_work()` in `check_direct` in a new process.